# Add gem to gemfile with bundler from command line

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

When using node package manager you can specify `npm install --save mynodemodule` which automatically pops the module in `package.json`

I was wondering if there is a command for bundler that allows you to add the gem and version to the gemfile from the command line?

For example `bundle install --save nokogiri`

Comment: Yeah, it looks like gem doesn't have this feature, that's weird, because almost every package manager has something similar.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you visit this question in 2018, `bundler` now has a cli to do this:

`bundle add <gem-name> <version>`

Version string could be your typical gem version including `>=` and `~`

Comment: This should be the default behavior of `gem install`. Nothing happens when you just do `gem install`, from what I can tell. It doesn't get installed in the project.

Comment: @AndrewKoster i'm late but the 'gem' gem is separate from rails, it is typically a system-wide gem packaged with Ruby containing executables used to install gems to the system, as well as package and publish gems. it has no concept of Bundler or a Gemfile, which are rails/application specific conventions.

Comment: I guess I forgot that unlike `npm` which can be used to install libraries globally or in a project folder, `gem` only does global installs. Probably because Rails didn't have a built-in Gemfile back when I first started using it.

Comment: Finally I found the answer for my doubt.

Answer (score 50):

Just wrote [Gemrat](https://github.com/DruRly/gemrat) to do this.

```
    $ gem install gemrat 
    $ gemrat nokogiri

    #=> gem 'nokogiri', '1.6.0' added to your Gemfile.
    #=> Bundling...
```

Comment: +1 for the awesome meme in the readme of Gemrat.  Also a good, convenient gem

Comment: I'm not convinced that locking the Gem to an exact version in the Gemfile by default is the best idea.  Gemfile.lock is there to lock the exact version.  Setting a minimum version, sure... but if I used this I'd either have to always use one of the other options or decide never to update my gems.

Comment: What about specifying environment? Like adding gems to only the test env, or prod, or dev?

Answer (score 25):

```
echo 'gem "nokogiri"' >> Gemfile
```

Comment: Not quite, I want it to install it locally, and also chuck in the version automatically too.

Comment: echo 'gem "nokogiri"' >> Gemfile && bundle install

Comment: I think Simon wants the equivalent of "npm install --save foo". If so, what is wanted is to download and install the latest version of gem foo, then add it to the Gemfile with a version qualifier based on the version that was actually downloaded and installed, e.g. gem "foo", "~> 1.2.3"

Answer (score 11):

as @zocoi described, you can use bundle and specify the group:

```
bundle add rails --group "development, test"
```

More information

```
bundle add --help
```